# Creating an Authentication to check if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app which communicates with a REST API. Sending a POST request to my api and in return `{ logged: false, username: undefined, id: undefined }` if the user is not logged in, otherwise, it will return something like `{ logged: true, username: 'admin', id: 123 }`.

I want these functions implemented in such a way that calling one will set the values for all the rest. 
I am getting post response in return , but I am quite confused about checking the condition.

Here is the service I have tried putting together:

```
app.factory('Authentication', function($http,session){
var service = {};

service.login = function(username,password) {
return $http
.post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo',{
    username : username,
    password : password
})
.then(
  function successCallback(response){
  session.create(response.data.id,response.data.username);
  return response.data;
});
};

service.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return !!session.username;
};
return service;
}); 

  /*-----Main Controller-----*/

app.controller('credientials',['$scope','$route','$http','Authentication',function($scope,$route,$http,Authentication) {

 $scope.isAuthenticated = false;

$scope.userCred = {
  username: '',
  password: ''
}

/*-----Form Submition-----*/

$scope.log = function(userCred){

Authentication.login(userCred.username,userCred.password)
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Please don't tell me to google it, because I already have so many blue links. If you know anything , please correct me and if you have any working example share it .

Answer (score 1):

Use a promise service `$q` in factory

```
app.factory('Authentication', function($http,$q,session){
  var service = {};

  service.login = function(username,password) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http
      .post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo',{
        username : username,
        password : password
      })
      .then(function successCallback(response){
          session.create(response.data.id,response.data.username);
          resolve(response.data);
      }, function(err){
          reject(err);
      });
    });
  };

  service.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return !!session.username;
  };
  return service;
});
```

Comment: how would i call the promise in the controller

Comment: Your current controller code is ok, will not need promise, but only in your factory.

Comment: Only remove the .catch method and change with this `Authentication.login(userCred.username,userCred.password)
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}, function(err){
    console.error(err);
});`

Comment: I implemented your code it's working fine. But when i enter the user credentials, it's not returning the promise response. Entered data is getting updated in the server

Comment: Please find out responses with `console.log` inside `.then` functions in factory

Comment: I did it. i am getting the post response, which has been entered in the text box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156909/discussion-between-miraz-chowdhury-and-srk).